# I want to wire a cigarette lighter plug to the back of my uhf radio to make it portable can I do this

Tags: uhf, installation, wiring

i have a uhf radio I want to wire a cigarette lighter plug to so it can be removed from the car and be put into another car is the possible or not plz help me with this matter

It is just a standed uniden uhf radio 12v dc and it draws 2 to 3 amps I think the only accessory on the lighter socket is a gps

Comment: You won't get much help if you don't specify transceiver brand, max power requirements, accessories, pictures.

Comment: Only if the person asking the question knows (or knows how to find) the current rating of a cigarette lighter socket in a car. I know it's 10A, and you know it's 10A, but I am prepared to give the asker the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Also, your question won't be taken seriously unless you put at least some effort into writing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

A standard car cigarette lighter socket is rated at up to 10A and 100W, so you have plenty of leeway.

Another question when moving from one car to another, is what to do about an antenna.

Comment: Yes I did know the socket is 10a thank you but the plug I am putting on there has a 1a fuse in it do I need to upgrade it to a 4a one and will the plug be ok with that.      Oh and the antenna is not a problem it is a magnetic base

Comment: You need a plug that is rated at more than 3A, and a fuse that matches the rating of the plug (or 10A, whichever is lower)

Comment: Thank you this answers  my questions in full much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Many vendors sell "batteries" which are just cigarette ("accessory port") lighter plugs on one end and a battery-shaped connector on the other.

They're perfect for cars.